# How to remove %22 from urls in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working in MVC 4 and using angularJs for client side scripting.I made an edit method which posts Id of the object to the MVC controller.When i click on edit . The url it generates is http://localhost:59568/NewsLetter/GetNewsLetterDataAng?id=%2256d6ac05afb241256469194b%22

but it should be

http://localhost:59568/NewsLetter/GetNewsLetterDataAng?id=56d6ac05afb241256469194b

Because of extra %22 in the front and end it is throwing 500 error.
Please suggest me how to remove it from the url

Comment: How do you pass your Id ?

Comment: @using a service function    'this.getNewsLetter = function (Id) {
        var response = $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/NewsLetter/GetNewsLetterDataAng',
            params: {
                id: JSON.stringify(Id)
            }
        });
        return response;
    }'

Comment: It's because you use `JSON.stringify` that method is producing a JSON string and that string conains quotes which are ulr encoded. Why do you need the `JSON.stringify` in the first place?

Comment: @MihailStancescu I am new to angularjs .I am following a tutorial.This is how they used it.So i just followed the same steps

Comment: Try it without `JSON.stringify`, just pass the id.

Comment: @MihailStancescu It worked, Thankyou sir!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the comment above I'll let you know an other thing about how to send and get data using angular js.

If you want to pass a json object to the server it's better to do it in a `POST` using the `$http` service builtin angular like in the example below:

```
$http.post(url, jsonObject){...};
```

By doing so, you send the json object as the body of the request and in asp.net-mvc the model binder can bind that json object to a class in your C# code.

In your case there is no need, as I said in the comments, for the `JSON.stringfy` method call when doing a `GET` request.

Comment: ThankYou for the info.It helped me in editing and adding the data